# How to localize my android application text?

Tags: android, localization

I am developing the android application for different language.I want to localize my application.
I am getting the language text from server 
 I want to change the text based on text retrieved from server.

Please any one help me in this

Answer (score 1):

You should start from Here. [Android Official Localization Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).... [This](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/) is one of the great tutorials I found.

Comment: i don't want to use the default Locale .I want to change the Locale based on the user selected language

Answer (score -1):

I think ttf files may help you.
Get the ttf files for all the languages and set the typeface to the text